# Java remove if condition don't work as it have to

Tags: java, for-loop, remove-if

Can have few plans and few tariffs. Need to remove all tariffs from plan, when `remove == N`. Tried to do it with this code, but nothing happens. I mean, I debugged and saw in console, that `remove is T`, but code don't remove tariffs anyway. How to fix removing?

```
    remove = "Y";
    List<Plan> plan = new ArrayList<Plan>();
    plan.addAll(plan2);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < plan.size(); i++) { 
        List<Tariff> tariff = new ArrayList<Tariff>();
        tariff.addAll(plan.get(i).getTariff());

        for (int j = 0; j < tariff.size(); j++) {  
            if(tariff.get(j).getCode().equals("N")) {
                remove = "N";
            }
        }
        plan.get(i).getTariff().removeIf(condition -> remove.equals("Y"));
    }
```

Comment: `condition -> remove.equals("Y")` is either true for all, or false for all. If you want to remove everything, use `.clear()`; if you don't want to remove things, just don't call anything.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Please explain your use case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is needed to remove all tariffs from a plan when *any* tariff has a code == `N`, this may be done as follows:

```
List<Plan> cleaned = new ArrayList<>(plan2);

cleaned.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getTariff().stream().anyMatch(t -> "N".equals(t.getCode())))
    .forEach(p -> p.getTariff().clear());
```